# BSONError: Invalid UTF-8 string in BSON document (mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid, mongodb-compass

I have a database which using mongo v3.4.3. I created a dump using `mongodump` command and restored using `mongorestore`to the same version of database.

I got an error

> Cannot create index in mongodb, key too large to index

but it was restored correctly using this `--noIndexRestore`  flag.

The problem is I want to restore the db to latest version of mongo (v6). when i run `mongorestore` command, it restores successfully but I'm getting

> BSONError: Invalid UTF-8 string in BSON document while retrieving this data.

I tried using compass and I'm facing the same error.

[image]

FYI I'm using this database with ruby on rails.

Comment: Looks like your MongoDB has some corrupt data. Did you try `mongoexport`? Then you can import with `mongoimport`. Or follow the [Upgrade a Standalone to 6.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/6.0-upgrade-standalone/). However, you would have to upgrade step by step, i.e. 3.4 -> 3.6 -> 4.0 -> 4.2 -> 4.4 -> 5.0 -> 6.0

Comment: That actually worked. As you said, there was some corrupt data in the collection. so I tried `mongoexport -d <database_name> -c <collection_name> -o /path/file.json`  and for restoring `mongoimport -d <database_name> -c <collection_name> -o /path/file.json`  and it worked well